# How comes there should be at least 6 characters to edit an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Sometimes, the answers may contains a typo or just a brackets or a parenthesis missing, correcting it won't be more than two characters. Then I just find the restrict is annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suggested edits require a review. To waste reviewers time over a two character change is not productive.

If the typo really is the only thing wrong with a post, surely it isn't all that important. In the rare cases where it is and there is really nothing else you can edit, leave it to users with 2k+ reputation; they can edit without that restriction.